# Passing from child to parent from a component with 3 objects

Tags: reactjs

I got a component with 2 buttons and 1 input text. The button 1 decrease a item and the button 2 increment a item to a input. I need to got the value from the input when I decrease/increment a item. The decrease/increment its working, but I can't (I don't know how) get  the value in parent component.
This is my child component, named ChooseQuantity:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ChooseQuantity.css';

class ChooseQuantity extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    state = {
        qtd: 0,
    }
    addItem(){
        this.setState({qtd: this.state.qtd + 1 });
    }
    removeItem(){
        if(this.state.qtd > 0){
            this.setState({qtd: this.state.qtd - 1 });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="minus" onClick={() => this.removeItem()}>
                    <i className="fas fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <input className="qtd" type="text" value={this.state.qtd} name='qtd' onChange={this.props.action} onInput={(e) => this.setState({ choose_quantity: e.target.value })} readOnly />
                <button className='plus' onClick={() => this.addItem()} >
                    <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ChooseQuantity;
```

This is part of my parent component, named Event (note that the child component it's in a array):

```js
{
  this.state.tickets.map((ticket, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                  <h3 className="ticket-name">{ ticket.name }</h3>
              </div>
          </div>
          {ticket.lot.map((lot, j) => 
              <div className="row" key={i}>
                  <div className="col-8">
                      <h5 className="lot-name">{ lot.name }</h5>
                      <h6 className="lot-price">
                          R$ { lot.price.replace('.', ',') } <br />
                          <small>(R$ { lot.price.replace('.', ',') } + R$ { lot.price_tax.replace('.', ',') })</small>
                      </h6>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-4">
                      <ChooseQuantity />
                      {this.state.qtd}
                  </div>
              </div>
          )}
          <hr />
      </div>
      )
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should 'lift up' the state in to a common parent that handles the logic and pass handlers like `onAddItem`, `onRemoveItem` and a `value` prop down to your buttons and input.

See here for detail on lifting state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html